# Jordan block: where (not) to place "one"?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have some $\lambda$ with algebraic multiplicity of $4$ and geometric multiplicity of $2$. As I understand, the Jordan block will be $4\times 4$ matrix and $2$ "ones" on the subdiagonal. The question is where to place these $2$ "ones", because I have $3$ free cells.

1. $$
           \begin{matrix}
           \lambda & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
           0 & \lambda & 1 & 0 \\
           0 & 0 & \lambda & 0 \\
           0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda \\
           \end{matrix}
   $$
2. $$
           \begin{matrix}
           \lambda & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
           0 & \lambda & 0 & 0 \\
           0 & 0 & \lambda & 1 \\
           0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda \\
           \end{matrix}
   $$
3. $$
           \begin{matrix}
           \lambda & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
           0 & \lambda & 1 & 0 \\
           0 & 0 & \lambda & 1 \\
           0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda \\
           \end{matrix}
   $$

Which variant to choose? And why?

Comment: The diagonal above the main diagonal is called a superdiagonal, not subdiagonal. Subdiagonal is the diagonal below the main one.

Answer (score 1):

Number 1 and number 3 are similar (in the technical sense). It doesn't matter which one you choose. Number 2 is different though. You don't get to choose between that and the other two; the original matrix forces one or the other.

Here is one easy way to distinguish them: In case 1, $(A-\lambda I)^2=0$. In case 2, that is not so.

Comment: So what you're saying is that which matrix you choose depends on the original matrix that $\lambda$ came from?

Comment: When you write a matrix in JCF, what you're doing is finding a conjugate of that matrix.  The information you're given isn't enough to determine a matrix up to conjugacy, as you've illustrated: there are either two 2x2 Jordan blocks, or one 3x3 and one 1x1 Jordan block.

Answer (score 1):

Up to similarity, 1. and 3. are the same. The geometric multiplicity is the number of Jordan blocks. So without further information, all you can say is that your 4-by-4 matrix is similar to 1. or 2. (3. being the same as 1. up to conjugation).